# Swift UI Stack on ontop of image

Tags: swiftui

I want to add my username stack, ontop of my image, but i am unsure on how to do this.

i want the image and the username stack and button ontop of the image.

[image]

My code is below:

```
   VStack(alignment: .leading) {

        HStack{
            
            Image("circle-placeholder").resizable().scaledToFill().frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(300)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                
                Text("Username").font(.system(size:15 , weight:.bold))
                Text("Country , City ").font(.system(size:15 , weight:.bold))
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis").frame(width: 28, height: 28)
                    .accentColor(.gray)
                
            }).padding()
        }
        
        Image("batman").resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(maxHeight:500)
            .clipped().cornerRadius(20).shadow(color: .gray, radius: 10)
        
        
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            FeedAction()
            Spacer()
        }.padding(-94)
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: you can do that by using a VStack. or there is any other complication?

Comment: Use can use a `ZStack`. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum i have updated

Comment: Not a picture actual code. Something to copy and paste and get a working View

Comment: @loremipsum done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an overlay so that it will be over your Image. Here is an example showing how you can achieve that. As I don't have the images I substituted them with `Rectangle()` and `Circle()`.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Rectangle() // replace this with your image
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .frame(maxHeight:500)
                .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 10)
                .overlay(
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Circle() // replace this with your image
                                .frame(width: 36, height: 36)

                            VStack(alignment: .leading){

                                Text("Username").font(.system(size:15 , weight:.bold))
                                Text("Country , City ").font(.system(size:15 , weight:.bold))
                            }

                            Spacer()

                            Button(action: {}, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                                    .frame(width: 28, height: 28)
                                    .accentColor(.gray)

                            })
                        }
                        .padding()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                )

            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Text("---") // I didn't have your FeedAction() code
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This is what it will look like

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but in my list i have a big space